# How can I implement a portable JPA isDirty() method?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to track changes in JPA OneToMany associations in order to notify subscribers of events that a region (one of these associations) of an object have been changed. I first tried to have a specialization of List which is aware of changes.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "col_name")
private List<SomeType>  oneOfManyLists = new CAArrayList<SomeType>();
```

My decorator looks like this:

```
public class CAArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    private boolean      changed = false;

    public CAArrayList() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean isChanged() {
        return changed;
    }

    // Mutable delegates
    @Override
    public boolean add( T e) {
        changed = true;
        return super.add( e );
    }
    ....
}
```

In the DAO I want to check which of the OneToMany associations have been changed, 
Unfortunatly the following line leads to an ClassCastException since Hibernate wraps my CAArrayList this with PersistentBag:

```
((CAArrayList) obj.getSomeList()).isDirty()
```

The next one works but is not portable between different implementations of JPA.

```
((PersistentBag) obj.getSomeList()).isDirty()
```

How should this be done in a portable way?

Comment: @Matt It is probably not so important, but our team is quite strict on such things, we are always looking for clean solutions. It might be that I've overlooked something in the JPA API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to do it at the wrong level (too low).

Rather than trying to track all internal changes to the list of SomeType, encapsulate the functional changes to this list in a specific service, to which all the other services (and the presentation layer) would delegate when this list must be modified. In this centralized service, notify the subscribers when the service changes the list of SomeType.